# INSERT INTO EXCEL (linked server) read-only

Tags: sql, sql-server, export-to-excel

I'm trying to insert a resultset into a linked server pointing to an Excel file.

Here is my script:

```
exec sp_addlinkedserver 
@server = N'ExcelTEST',
@srvproduct = N'Excel 12.0',
@provider = N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
@datasrc = N'\\MyServer\MyPath\MyFile.xlsx',
@provstr = N'Excel 12.0;HDR=No,IMEX=1'                    
 --
exec sp_addlinkedsrvlogin
    @rmtsrvname = N'ExcelTEST',
    @useself = N'False',
    @locallogin = NULL,
    @rmtuser = NULL,
    @rmtpassword = NULL 
GO
--
INSERT INTO ExcelTEST...[Sheet2$] 
SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM dbo.myTable
GO

sp_dropserver N'ExcelTEST', 'droplogins'
GO
```

I then get the following error:

> OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server
>   "ExcelTEST" returned message "Cannot update. Database or object is
>   read-only.".
>
> Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 6 The OLE DB provider
>   "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "ExcelTEST" reported an
>   error. The provider indicates that the user did not have the
>   permission to perform the operation.
>
> Msg 7343, Level 16, State 2, Line 6 The OLE DB provider
>   "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "ExcelTEST" could not
>   INSERT INTO table "[ExcelTEST]...[Sheet2$]".

How can I make the connection to the Excel file read-write?

Comment: [Have you considered just using the Export Wizard for this instead?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/87772/643591)

Comment: what error on first exec sp_addlinkedserver...?

Comment: Export Wizard won't work as I'm hoping to use the query in SSIS to automate the data pull.

The linked server is showing it is read-only, it would need to be changed to read-write which is where the issue is.  However, we may have found a better solution than using a linked server due to the sheer number of Excel files that need to be loaded and our service account won't have permission to create/drop linked servers.