# is there any Query to save the Data in Excel File

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table **students** that contains 100 Records.

Now i'm going to Run a Query

```
select * from Students
```

I Copy the **Students Data** and Paste it in My **Excel File**

After some Time i inserted another 100 Records now again i'm going to run the Query copy the Data and Paste it in **Excel File**

Every Time copied and Paste in Excel File.

**Is there any Alternate way or Query that directly save the Data in my Excel File**

Comment: you can make a simple exe file that will query the database and get records and copy it into uour excel file..
which language do you code in..?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/87772/284240

Comment: Can you post code ? you must be getting data in Dataset or DataTable rite? So can you not loop and insert?

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way would be accessing database table by creating a data connection from excel. I assume you are using Sql server database.

1. In Excel go to the Data tab
2. Select relevant data source in the "From Other Sources" drop down
3. Select Sql server and give necessary conection information and select the table you wanted while navigating through.
4. Select "Table" as prefered view option and it will show the table in excel.
5. When a change happen in the database simply right click the excel table and Refresh it

Comment: It's good but if i have a condition in my Query then what should i do...?

Comment: There is an option in the "From Other Sources" drop down as "From Microsoft Query". Using that option you can build query using query wizard.