# Exporting the output of a stored proc. to excel

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to export the result of a stored procedure execution to a excel worksheet,I want to set this up as a Job which will generate the result and store it in a excel worksheet.Is this possible I have googled it but not found any convincing workable solutions

Comment: Scheduled SSIS package, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/87772/246342

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use INSERT INTO OPENROWSET, for example:

```
INSERT INTO OPENROWSET ('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 'Excel 8.0;Database=D:\Output.xls;', 'EXEC   [dbo].[spName] ''param''') EXEC [dbo].[spName] 'param'
```

You should enable Ad Hoc Distributed Queries before:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'ad hoc distributed queries', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

Comment: Can I specify a execute statement in place of select here!