# how to export sql table data into excel worksheet?

Tags: sql, excel, sql-server-2012

I have this table that I want to export its data into my excel file.
so far I've tried every topic here but nothing worked.
I've tried these 2:

```
insert into OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 
    'Excel 8.0;Database=D:\excel\testing.xls;', 
    'SELECT * FROM [newStart$]') select * from OutputResult


insert into OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
    'Excel 8.0;Database=D:\excel\testing.xls;', 
    'SELECT * FROM [newStart$]') select * from OutputResult
```

when I run it with jet I'll get this error:

```
OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)" returned message "The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object 'newStart$'.  Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly.".
 Msg 7350, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 Cannot get the column information from OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)".
```

and when I ran the ACE.OLEDB I get this one:

```
OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" returned message "The Microsoft Office Access database engine could not find the object 'newStart$'.  Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly.".
Msg 7350, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot get the column information from OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)".
```

I give my sql account full control permission as well.
plus I run these two as well:

```
USE [master]
GO
EXEC master . dbo. sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' , N'AllowInProcess' , 1
GO

EXEC master . dbo. sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' , N'DynamicParameters' , 1
GO
```

2:

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
```

I would appreciate it if anyone could point me into the right direction.

Comment: You can use SSIS to do this, if that is an option you have

Answer (score 0):

```
strSqlQry = "Place SQL Qry Here"
vFilePath = "Database Path"

'Create Objects
Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

'Open Connection
conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
"Data Source=" & vFilePath & ";" & _
 "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;"";"

'Execute Qry
rs.Open strSqlQry, conn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic

'Place recorset into excel worksheet
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset (NewRS)

rs.Close

Set rs = Nothing
Set conn = Nothing
```

Comment: I'm new with the concept of sql now, should I put this in my store procedure?

Comment: cause I want it to generate with sql query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use way written in this topic [How do you transfer or export SQL Server 2005 data to Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87735/how-do-you-transfer-or-export-sql-server-2005-data-to-excel)

In excel using External data menu connect to database

Comment: before I ask the question I went through all of these topics. but thanks anyway.